# При парсинге страницы на cheerio проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

На некоторых сайтах при парсинге страницы вместо текста выдает что-то такое: `&#x43E;&#x43A;&#x43B;&#x430;&#x441;&#x441;&#x43D;`

Вот код:

```
var request = require('request');
var tress = require('tress');
var fs = require('fs');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var URL = 'https://readrate.com/rus/ratings/top100';

var q = tress((url, callback) => {
  request(url, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    const $ = cheerio.load(body, { decodeEntities: true });
    var link = '';

    console.log($.html());

    callback();
  }); 
});

q.drain = function() {
   require('fs').writeFileSync('./data.json', JSON.stringify(results, 
null, 4)); 
};

q.push(URL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> console.log($.html());
> ```

Ну так ты просишь html-разметку, вот он её и выводит. Возможно, ты на самом деле хочешь метод `text`, а не `html`, но уж точно не на всей странице.

Comment: проблема в том что он тогда не может нормально считать классы внутри тегов на странице и в итоге при коде "console.log($('books-list').text());" он выводит пустую строку, хотя тег с таким классом есть

Comment: @ПавелКривенко, а ничего, что в селекторе перед именем класса надо ставить точку? А ты вместо класса выбираешь по тэгу.

Comment: мда, во я тормоз